# Pandas: Get top n columns based on a row values

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

Having a dataframe with a single row, I need to filter it into a smaller one with filtered columns based on a value in a row.
What's the most effective way?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1], 'b':[10], 'c':[3], 'd':[5]})
```

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 3 | 5 |

For example top-3 features:

| b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 5 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sorting per row and select first 3 values:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(0, axis=1, ascending=False).iloc[:, :3]
print (df1)
    b  d  c
0  10  5  3
```

Solution with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[0].nlargest(3).to_frame().T
print (df1)
    b  d  c
0  10  5  3
```

Comment: this solution is working only for 1d, no?

Comment: @SuperMario yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose `T`, and use `nlargest()`:

```
new = df.T.nlargest(columns = 0, n = 3).T

print(new)

   b  d  c
0  10  5  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.argsort` to get the solution. This Numpy method, in the below code, gives the indices of the column values in descending order. Then slicing selects the largest n values' indices.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1], 'b':[10], 'c':[3], 'd':[5]})

# Pick the number n to find n largest values
nlargest = 3

# Get the order of the largest value columns by their indices
order = np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :nlargest]

# Find the columns with the largest values
top_features = df.columns[order].tolist()[0]

# Filter the dateframe by the columns
top_features_df = df[top_features]

top_features_df
```

output:

```
    b   d   c
0   10  5   3
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add a little more textual information: How and why does it work? What makes it different from the other answers given?